# SQL Server 2019 Local Instance

Tags: login, sql-server

I connected to my SQL Server Local Instance yesterday using windows authentication. But today I am not able to connect and getting the error -
Error Number: 18456
Severity: 14
State: 5
Line Number: 65536
Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ]
Also I checked the services and Configuration manager - All up and running.

PS - the only change I made was, Copied master and mastlog files from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Template Data to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA to get the SQL Agent running.

Can you please let me know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please let me know what could be the issue?

Based on the fact, the error number is **18456** and the state is **5**, the login you are attempting to use is invalid.  I would first verify if a role for the user in question has been set for the database.

> 1. Under your server, unfold 'Security', unfold 'Logins', right click on the login, select 'Properties'
> 2. Go to the 'User Mapping' tab, and select the DB you want. In the lower part of the screen, select the memberships (or rights) you want
>    to assign to the login.

You might also want to check if the username you are using is correct.

> This state occurs when a SQL server login logs in with the name that doesn’t exist in sql server.

Source:

- [Can't Connect To SQL Server with the Newly Create Login Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665179/cant-connect-to-sql-server-with-the-newly-create-login-name)
- [2 Common Errors and Reasons for SQL Server Login Failures](https://logicalread.com/errors-sql-server-login-failures-pd01/)
- [Troubleshooting Login failed Error 18456](http://sql-articles.com/articles/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-login-failed-error-18456/)

Comment: Sadly, the two users over at Stack Overflow did not provide their exact error message, so I am unable to verify if they received the same error message.  So I have to go by a single keyword that both users used and extrapolate a conclusion based on my knowledge of SQL Server.

Comment: @Ramhond - Sorry  I am not able to connect to the Instance , but how will I check the Logins properties? Is there any other way please?

Comment: @Jeni - Before I attempt to figure that out.  Have you actually verified you are using the correct user?  State 5 is specifically linked to trying to use an username that does not exist.  This isn't the case of you trying to use a Windows account, when SQL Server was expecting a SQL username, since that would have an entirely different state.  *It appears that you are attempting to use a SQL username that does not exist instead of your Windows account.*  You should be able to manage the local MSSQL instance.

Comment: Yes I am.. I used windows authentication and connected to the Local instance a couple of days before and it was working fine. Suddenly it stopped working now. Its weird

Comment: “ I connected to my SQL Server Local Instance yesterday using windows authentication.” - State 5 is indicating that SQL username your attempting to use doesn’t exist.  Go back to Windows  Authentication method